# Send email using environment variables via Django for security

Tags: django, email, django-views, environment-variables

I can send emails using environment variables in my settings.py, however how do I input these variables in views.py? When put the actual email in str--it works; but for extra security, I written it as env. variable and gave me an error: SMTPRecipientsRefused. Also, how do I get it to show the sender's email. It shows in the console, but not when I receive the email. I am trying to get different users to send to one email recipient as contact form.

settings.py:

```py
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
EMAIL_HOST_USER=os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

views.py:

```py
def contact(request):
  message = request.POST.get('message', '')
  from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '')

  send_mail('Contact Form', message, from_email, ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'])
  return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

contact.html:

```html
<form action="/contact" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="email" name="from_email" placeholder="Your email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message...">
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You are sending the email from the address filled in the form, do you have the credentials for that email? Usually you send the emails only from the ```DEFAULT_FROM_ADDRESS``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Comment: Thank you Pedro for your response (and edit). I managed to get the env variable to work in views.py; however, everytime I send from a different email--it shows the email from my env variable. I am trying to make a contact form where users can post their email and send to the email that's in my env variable. The from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '') so the recipient have a way to reply whatever email the users posted.

Answer (score 2):

To use your project's settings in views.py you need to import the object django.conf.settings.

Change your views.py to:

```
from django.conf import settings

def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '')
        send_mail('Contact Form', message, from_email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER])

    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

Comment: Thank Aedry, it works! I also found that EMAIL_HOST_USER=os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER') can also be used. However, it still shows the from_email from my env variable. Does request.POST work as above? I would like the recipient to be able to reply. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this work? I've add a check if request.method == 'POST'

Comment: I've had the "if request.method=='POST'---but I am still showing the from_email as the same email I sent to :/

Comment: In order to send emails with google you have to provide the EMAIL_HOST_USER with EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings to authenticate to google SMTP server. So if you in your form you'll also have to collect the password to the "from_email". check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail. In particular see the auth_user and auth_password. If this isn’t provided, Django will use the value of the EMAIL_HOST_USER setting.

Comment: @Keiko have a look at Django's EmailMessage class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects, they allow you to easily add a "reply_to" field which you can set to the posters email address so you can reply directly to the poster form your environ email address

Comment: Thank you Aedry and Omar; I am concerned once it's being deployed on AWS--would it still work for a client to use since the values are on my local machine? Also, if I open up a yahoo account, would it involve less authentication especially involving from_email? Thank you for your patience.